# MSSQL 2000/2005 Server maximum memory limit

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server

We are attempting to export about 30 GB database via 1C accounting application. The SQL server is at 20% CPU utilization and appears to use all available ram - 2GB out of 4. I've read about the [/3GB flag](http://www.sqlnewsgroups.net/group/microsoft.public.sqlserver.server/topic24296.aspx), but we would like to stuff more memory into server and have SQL server use more. What do I have to do? Will just upgrading Windows 2003 Server from Standard Edition to Enterprise Edition help?

Comment: Please can you clarify which version of SQL server (2000 or 2005 you specify both in the question title)?  Which edition of SQL server?  32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, it is 2000, 32 bit.

Comment: Thanks Konrads, and what's the edition of SQL server? (Enterprise / Standard etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the table right at the bottom of [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933149(SQL.80).aspx), SQL 2000 standard edition won't use more than 2GB of ram, but depending on what server OS you are running, the Enterprise Edition of SQL Server 2000 can use up to 64 GB of RAM.

It's all about [pricing and market segmentation](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/CamelsandRubberDuckies.html), I'm afraid.

Comment: I think this is the ultimate cause. I wonder if there is a quick way to upgrade 2000 Std to EE for migration.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to go for x64 architecture, if you want to get all the benefits from added RAM. The things would work much more natively in that way. We have several highloaded instances of 1C (16GB of RAM on SQL and application servers), SQL2005 x64 works well on Windows Server 2003 R2 x64 edition. As for application server (if you need it), we use Terminal Services on Windows Server 2003 x64 and also 2008 x64 and everything goes OK. The version of 1C is 8.0, I'm not sure if the things are all right if you mean 7.7, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running 32bit SQL with one instance, than no. 3GB is max.